# Для нестатического поля требуется ссылка на объект

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Начал проходить курс ASP.NET Core и возникла ошибка:

> Ошибка    CS0120  Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства "Startup._env" требуется ссылка на объект.

Код:

```
IWebHostEnvironment _env;
private Startup(IWebHostEnvironment env) //конструктор Startup
{
    _env = env;
}
app.Map("/aboutproject", AP);
private static void AP(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.Run(async context => {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync($"The project name: {_env.ApplicationName}"); // тут ошибка
    });
}
```

Comment: уберите `static`

Comment: попытка вызвать нестатическое поле из статического метода класса
все логично, что ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь вызвать из статичного метода не статичный метод.
Варианты решения (Выбирайте по вашей ситуации, я думаю вам нужно 2 вариант):

1. Сделать статичным метод Startup и _evn.
2. Убрать статичность у AP